# Java: как указать дефолтное значение для Feign

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-ee

Подскажите, как можно установить значение по умолчанию в параметре в Feign клиенте?
Вот мой код. 
Я указал значение по умолчанию, но оно не работает :(

Сервис:

```
public Price get(PricesRequest request) {
        return  priceFeignClient.get(
                       request.getPrice(),
                       request.getAddress(),
                       request.getCode(),
                       request.getCurrency()
                )
}
```

Feign:

```
public interface PriceFeignClient {
    @GetMapping
    Price get(@RequestParam("price") String price,
              @RequestParam("address") String Address,
              @RequestParam(value = "code", required = true, defaultValue = "AAA") String code,
              @RequestParam("currency") String currency
    );
}
```

Я хочу сделать значение по умолчанию для параметра "code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена следующим образом:

добавил это в главный api на том сервере, на который я стучался (т.е. на принимающей стороне, а не на отправляющей запрос).

```
@RequestParam(value = "code", required = false, defaultValue = "AAA") String code
```

обязательно надо required = false (вместо required = true).